flex items not shrinking (tailwind css)
To be viewed on mobile screen size.
Each image is in a div that's display flex
Each image is set to a big size.
The flex shrink is set on all images, but theyare not shrinking.
The images are overflowing the flex container.
Expected behavior: All images should shrink so they are all showing on screen without wrapping like in this picture..

https://play.tailwindcss.com/rP79Yfa2IR
<div class="bg-black p-4">
  <div class="flex">
    <img class="h-96 w-96 flex-shrink" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491528323818-fdd1faba62cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="" />
    <img class="h-96 w-96 flex-shrink" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550525811-e5869dd03032?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="" />
    <img class="h-96 w-96 flex-shrink" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500648767791-00dcc994a43e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2.25&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="" />
    <img class="h-96 w-96 flex-shrink" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>



You could use w-full max-w-96 aspect-square on each img element. Flex Children grow and shrink per default. But you gave them a fixed size so they cannot grow or shrink. With w-full max-w-96 they have a dynamic width up to 96

<div class="bg-black p-4">
  <div class="flex flex-wrap">
    <img class="max-w-full h-auto" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491528323818-fdd1faba62cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80"   
 alt="" />
    <img class="max-w-full   
 h-auto" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550525811-e5869dd03032?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="" />
    <img class="max-w-full   
 h-auto" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500648767791-00dcc994a43e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2.25&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="" />
    <img class="max-w-full   
 h-auto" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>


i am trying to get the images to be all horizontal instead of wrapping

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
